# Calculating capacitor value to mitigate voltage drop

Tags: power-supply, capacitance

A similar question has been asked [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/608547/how-to-calculate-capacitor-size-to-mitigate-voltage-drop-caused-by-current-peak) but I'm not entirely sure how to apply the accepted answer to my problem.

I have an ESP8266 Module that draws quite a lot of current when turned on. (I don't know *how much* exactly ; I assume something between 200-250mA)

Here's a view of the supply voltage (3.3V) when the ESP is turned on:

[image]

You can see it's pretty bad, over 0.5V drop over about 20μs.

I've added 2 100μF ceramic capacitors on the supply line and the voltage drop significantly decreased:

[image]

Now it's only about 250mV over 20μs.

I tried a couple of different capacitor values (more 100μFs, 47μF, 100nF) but the spike does not improve by a lot.

Instead of trying out different values, I'd be pretty happy if someone can show me how to calculate the correct capacitance instead of just trying out what works (it's a PCB with SMD capacitors ; quite a pain to stack them).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, the more beneficial place is to add the capacitors on the input side of the 3.3 volt regulator rather than the output side. If indeed that is what you are currently doing (your question isn't 100% clear in that respect) then also add them to the output of the regulator.

Having said that, a 250 mV glitch on the 3.3 volt rail shouldn't be a showstopper.

> *Instead of trying out different values, I'd be pretty happy if someone
> can show me how to calculate the correct capacitance instead of just
> trying out what works*

The basic formula that applies is that for a capacitor: -

$$i_C = C\cdot\dfrac{dv}{dt}$$

- In your case \$dv\$ is the 250 mV glitch.
- It looks like it happens in about 5 μs (if I read your scope picture correctly).
- That's the \$dt\$ bit.
- You have said the current pulse is maybe 250 mA and that's the \$i_C\$ bit.

The rest is just picking up your calculator.

However, your 3.3 volt regulator may just not be man-enough for the job.

---

Given that the calculation route yields 5 μF and that 100 μF has already been tried on the regulator output, my strong suspicion is that the 5 volt input to the regulator is also suffering and falling below the minimum input operating voltage.

Comment: _"Usually, the more beneficial place is to add the capacitors on the input side of the 3.3 volt regulator rather than the output side."_ Thanks! No, I placed them on the output, not input! How do you come to the value of 5 μs?

Comment: Of course I used the recommended capacitor values for the voltage regulator (it's an AP7361EA-33E-13 from Diodes Inc.) it's an LDO regulating 5V to 3.3V.

Comment: I looked at your 2nd picture and interpreted the horizontal scale as 20 us per division then, the fall looked to be over one quarter of a division. You should see that the 5 volts isn't also glitching below the input drop-out voltage for the regulator.

Comment: Oh, I always assumed you would take the duration of the voltage drop (i.e. 20 μs) instead of the fall.

Comment: We are interested in dv/dt and, it's biggest (in this example) when the glitch initially occurs.

Comment: I had a suspicion that 47μF is probably too big to make a difference. Punching in the numbers (250mV, 5μs, 250mA) gives me 5μF. Need to try that.

Comment: If 100 uF isn't proving much help then 5 uF is not going to help either so, your estimate of the peak draw is either miles away from reality or the input supply to the regulator is also dropping too low. I've double check that 5 uF is the correct value from the formula I gave.

Comment: Thanks for the tip measuring the input voltage. It looks pretty horrible: https://ibb.co/pwrn1YS. Blue is input voltage (5V, with 100μF in parallel), Yellow is "Regulated" 3.3V output. The 5V Source is a USB-Charging Brick (Apple's 5W Charger).

Comment: I read that USB-Devices should not have an input capacitance more than 10μF that's why I've been a bit hesitant to add more input capacitance. I've added 100μF in parallel to the power supply nevertheless, but it didn't help much.

Comment: How many volts does the 5 volt input go down to during the glitch. It looks like it drops nearly a volt and, that may be just too much for the regulator that follows. Anyhow, that's the area to concentrate on IMHO.

Comment: Thanks so far! You certainly saved me countless hours because I wouldn't have checked the input supply line (doh). I replaced the Apple Charger with my Lab Power Supply (set to current limit 2A) and it still doesn't look great: https://ibb.co/wNJ233g.

Comment: I think you'll have to assume that the current pulse is over an amp and quite possibly several amps. I don't think I can offer any more advice on this realistically other than try and track down what generates the pulse of current.

Comment: That's okay! I'm aware that this is _really_ difficult for you to help me remotely. I appreciate your help and time! I'll try with different amperage values and see if that changes anything.

Comment: I think I found the root cause: I placed some bypass capacitors right next to the ESP-Header with the following values: 10uF, 4.7uF, 100nF, 10nF and 1nF. Removing the bigger caps (10uF and 4.7uF) made the voltage drop considerably smaller. Basically my setup is like this:

Vcc <--> Relay Switch <--> Bypass Caps <--> ESP.

I think it was a mistake to place the large bypass caps AFTER the switch.

Comment: I think because the big bypass caps were after the switch, I overwhelmed the voltage regulator. I should've placed those BEFORE the switch, not after.

Comment: I can't visualize what you mean but it's good you are solving the problem

Comment: I have it like this: https://ibb.co/gjX4NY0 , but it would be much better to have it like this: https://ibb.co/ZWNhnX4. Do you agree? In the first circuit, the capacitor only gets charged when the relay switch is closed. In the second circuit, the capacitor is pre-charged and can supply the current once the relay switch is closed. Hope that makes sense

Comment: I think the basic question you first raised is answered and now we are in the realms of a brand new question which will attract a bunch of other people to make their suggestions on fixing the problem I highlighted.